# Pass array to where in Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table in my database with adminId and clientId

There might be 20 records with the adminId of the logged in user and I'm trying to pull a list of clients.

I am wondering if there is a way i can say something like:

```
$this->db->where('id', '20 || 15 || 22 || 46 || 86');
```

I'm trying to do this with dynamic data (you never know how many clients Id's you'll need to pull). Any ideas?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
$this->db->where_in('id', ['20','15','22','42','86']);
```

Reference: [where_in](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in)

Comment: How can I do this with an array for multiple conditions ? I have a foreach loop like foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {$query = $query->where_in($column,$value);} But this is not putting the quotes and so producing wrong query. How can I correct it

Comment: @HappyCoder: you need to merge arrays and pass to where_in:
For eg:
$one_array=array(10,20);
$two_array=array(30,40);
$final_array=array_merge($one_array,$two_array);
$this->db->where_in('id', $final_array);

Answer (score 18):

Use [where_in()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

```
$ids = array('20', '15', '22', '46', '86');
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids );
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 12):

From the Active Record docs:

```
$this->db->where_in();
```

Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right its right there in the docs. I've actually got them open and I guess I glazed over it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with AND if appropriate,

```
$this->db->where_in()
ex :  $this->db->where_in('id', array('1','2','3'));
```

Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with OR if appropriate

```
$this->db->or_where_in()
ex :  $this->db->where_in('id', array('1','2','3'));
```