# How to check multiple values in an array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to check multiple values in an array in codeigniter...

I only know this...

```
$vehicles = array('Car','Bike','Plane','Bus');
$this->db->where_in('Car,Bike', $vehicles);
```

please help me...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array to where in Codeigniter Active Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717555/pass-array-to-where-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this code

```
$vehicles = array('car'=>'car','bike'=>'bike');
$this->db->where_in($vehicles);
```

Thank you
***Heart to try.it work***

Answer (score 0):

Like in https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html source, first parameter in where_in should be table column name.

According to your last comment: You can with `array_slice`
 
function get first two elements of array: 
`$vehicles = array('Car','Bike','Plane','Bus');
$slicedArray = array_slice($vehicles, 0, 2);
$this->db->where_in('column_name', $slicedArray);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question, but i think you are looking for this:

```
$vehicles = array('Car','Bike','Plane','Bus');
$this->db->where_in('vehicle', $vehicles); //assuming vehicle is the name of a
//column in your database. Result will be:
// WHERE vehicle IN ('Car', 'Bike', 'Plane', 'Bus');
```

Comment: SIr, thanks for answering... But, i want to check car, bike in vehicle column.. i mean more than one value... How to do it ??