# Unable to delete multiple user using jquery and ajax (codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete a record by its row ID from a table using **PHP** and **AJAX** but when I click on the button it shows an error performing the action. When I inspect the code, it shows me an error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Here's my JS function:

```
function deleteSelUser()
{
    var data = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='id[]']:checked"), function () {
        data.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (data == "")
    {
        swal("Error", "Please select at least one user.", "error");
        return false;
    }
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this users!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
            function () {

                //console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    url: SITE_URL + "depositoradmin/delete_select_user",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {depositor_user_id: data},
                    success: function (res) {
                        // '.loader').hide();
                        var response = JSON.parse(res);
                        if (response.status == 1)
                        {
                            // swal("Success", response.msg, "success");
                            swal("Deleted!", response.msg, "success");
                            location.reload();
                        } else
                        {
                            swal("Error", response.msg, "error");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

here's my controller function:

```
function delete_select_user ()
{
    $depositor_user_id = implode("," , $this->input->post('depositor_user_id'));
    $data = array('is_deleted' => 1);
    $optresult = $this->depositor->delete_user_multiple($depositor_user_id , $data , 'depositor_user');
    if ($optresult) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 1 , 'msg' => "User deleted successfully"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 0 , 'msg' => "User not deleted"));
    }
}
```

end here's my model function:

```
public function delete_user_multiple($depositor_user_id, $data, $table_name) {
    $this->db->where('user_id IN(' . $depositor_user_id . ')');
    $this->db->update($table_name, $data);
    return $depositor_user_id;
}
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check your servers error log to see the actual error message. Also, you're wide open to SQL injections. Never put user data directly into your query like that. Use their method `$this->db->where_in('id', $arrayWithIds)` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717555/pass-array-to-where-in-codeigniter-active-record

Comment: Check error_log to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A where_in method exist for CI 3.1.19

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

```
$optresult = $this->depositor->delete_user_multiple($depositor_user_id , $data , 'depositor_user');
    if ($optresult) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 1 , 'msg' => "User deleted successfully"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 0 , 'msg' => "User not deleted"));
    }
```

It's better to try catch instead of testing the result (it can happen that the query will return 0 because the record has been already deleted) and you can print the exception message to see what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

the error come from my model controller i used wrong db key user_id the correct key from db is current_user_id

```
public function delete_user_multiple($depositor_user_id, $data, $table_name) {
$this->db->where('user_id IN(' . $depositor_user_id . ')');
$this->db->update($table_name, $data);
return $depositor_user_id;}
```