# Codeigniter combines the query inside a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have an array of IDs and I am fetching the details of those items from the database. I created a foreach loop to get each item one by one then push it to the array before returning to the controller. The problem is the query builder combines all the IDs in one single query.

```
public function get_product_by_ids($ids) {
        $products = array();
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('products')->row_array();

            array_push($products, $query);
        }

    return $products;
}
```

Here is the result of that code, using the profiler.

My IDs are

```
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 21
)
```

The produced query from the profiler:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `product_id` = '22'
AND `product_id` = '18'
AND `product_id` = '21'
AND `product_id` = '22' 

SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `product_id` = '18' 

SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `product_id` = '21'
```

Output:
The first one is empty, then I got the second up to the last.

I tried using where_in() as for @danblack said and here is the produced query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `product_id` = '22'
AND `product_id` = '18'
AND `product_id` = '21'
AND `product_id` IN('22', '18', '21')
```

Here are my new codes:

```
public function get_product_by_ids($ids) {
        $this->db->where_in('product_id', $ids);
        $query = $this->db->get('products')->result_array();

        return $query;
}
```

Output: Empty Array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array to where in Codeigniter Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717555/pass-array-to-where-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: @danblack I edited the codes with your solution but still, codeigniter is still adding those where clause.

Comment: danblack's solution will work as long as you don't have it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a problem with CodeIgniter (on codeigniter 3.x) or I made something wrong, but here is my temporary solution:

```
public function get_product_by_ids($ids) {
        $newquery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN(";

        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $newquery .= "'".$id."'";
            if($counter < (sizeof($ids) - 1)) {
                $newquery .= ", ";
            }
            $counter++;
        }

        $newquery .= ")";
        $query = $this->db->query($newquery)->result_array();

        return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public function get_product_by_ids($ids) {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('products');
      $this->db->where_in('product_id', $ids);//$ids should be array
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return $query->result_array();
      }else{
         return array();
      }
}
```